# Sublime 3 - Command not working under Windows 7

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have created a custom Sublime plugin [see code on github](https://github.com/ediathome/DJPreview). Everything works fine under OSX, but under Windows the command dj_preview does not work.

The command is defined in [DJPreview.py](https://github.com/ediathome/DJPreview/blob/master/DJPreview.py):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import webbrowser, sys, os
import tempfile
import codecs

from .markdown2 import Markdown

class DjPreviewCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
      full_range = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
...
```

The "Default (Windows).sublime-keymap" file looks like this:

```
[
   { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+r"], "command": "dj_preview"
   }
]
```

When I enable command logging with sublime.log_commands(True) the command the command is output to the console, but not executed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What happens if you open the Sublime console and enter `view.run_command("dj_preview")`?

Comment: Nothing, actually it just outputs ```>>> view.run_command("dj_preview")```

Comment: My guess is that somehow the command script in DJPreview is not found or that there is something wrong with my function or file names? Maybe an lowercase - uppercase conflict somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake: I placed the DJPreview.py file in the following subfolder:
`Data/Packages/User/DJPreview/DJPreview.py`

Whereas it needs to be in the following folder:
`Data/Packages/User/DJPreview.py`

Actually I just found that it's best to place the whole plugin folder in:
`Data/Packages/DJPreview/` and everything works!